# Загрузка очень большого числа строк в БД

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Есть потребность вставить очень большое число строк в БД. В связи с этим, возникли вопросы:

- 1. Какое количество строк целесообразно вставлять за один запрос?
- 2. Есть ли для вставки больших массивов данных в БД способ лучше, чем делать большое число INSERT запросов?

Comment: о какой БД идет речь? И каков формат входных данных - CSV, другая таблица, что-то еще?

Comment: @MaxU, БД - MSSQL, файл с данными могу привести и к CSV, если этот формат чем-то лучше.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я бы в данном случае воспользовался [BCP (*Bulk Copy Program*)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/tools/bcp-utility?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15), которая была специально разработана для загрузки большого объема данных в MS SQL Server.

Пример:

```
bcp WorlWideImporters.Warehouse.StockItemTransactions OUT D:\BCP\StockItemTransactions_native.bcp -m 1 -b 10000 -n -e D:\BCP\Error_out.log -o D:\BCP\Output_out.log -S -T
```

Если вам надо делать это программным путем воспользуйтесь [BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188365.aspx).

Пример:

```
BULK INSERT AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderDetail  
   FROM 'f:\orders\lineitem.tbl'  
   WITH   
      (  
         FIELDTERMINATOR =' |',  
         ROWTERMINATOR =' |\n'  
      );
```

По ссылкам выше можно найти больше примеров использования.

Comment: Один из примеров "в студию" прикрепите к своему ответу, вдруг ссылка станет не актуальной.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V,  об этом я не подумал, спасибо! Сейчас добавлю...